# Alfresco export file by ftp

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

Good day. I use the standard alfresco job and i need to save the line in a csv file and then transfer this file via FTP to a remote server. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

First You have to unable ftp in alfresco.add below propertie in alfresco-global.properties file

ftp.enabled=true
ftp.port=21

You can use any ftp file client to transfer file and also you can use window explorer to transfer file.Open window explorer and enter url "ftp:\localhost\Alfresco". here localhost is ip address

Comment: On Linux boxes this only works if Alfresco is running as root which you should never do. If you are running Alfresco as a non-root user, use a higher, non-privileged port, like 2121. You can then use a port-forwarding rule to forward traffic from 21 to port 2121 so that users can use the standard FTP port.